# Use double quote in grep to match end of line

Tags: regex, sed, csh, tcsh

I am using grep to match file names within Cshell.
I would like to match all files which fit
$name.
without having any other files match such as 
$name..

When forcing the match to appear at the end of the line by using dollar sign it works good. Only problem is that when i want to use a variable $name i must then use double quotes "" instead of '' and then $ does not work.

```
> ls back_dir | grep 'aa\.[0-9]$'
aa.1
aa.2

>ls back_dir | grep "aa\.[0-9]$"
Illegal variable name.
```

Comment: Don't use C-shell for scripting or you will be tearing your hair out over stuff like this for the foreseeable future. Google "C shell why not".

Comment: You probably need to see this: [Top Ten Reasons not to use the C shell](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt).  The first reason would tell what you're running into.

Comment: @devnull - great link. It actually shows this exact problem, including both my "solution" (not working and now deleted) and the correct (but wtf?!!) approach. Ed's advice is clearly sound. I love Bruce Barnett's writing. His `awk` tutorial is still my favorite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also mix `"` and `'`:

```
ls back_dir | grep "aa.[0-9]"'$'
```

(NB: Works in `bash` and C-shell.)